# Get previous LI with condition

Tags: jquery

I can't get my head around this. Seems to be easy.

```
<ul class="steps anchor">
<li><a href="#step-1" class="done" isdone="1" rel="1"><label class="stepNumber">1</label></a></li>
<li><a href="#step-2" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="2"><label class="stepNumber">2</label></a></li>
<li><a href="#step-3" class="selected" isdone="1" rel="3"><label class="stepNumber">3</label></a></li>
<li><a href="#step-4" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="4"><label class="stepNumber">4</label></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want:
I want to select the current Li (class="selected") (=3)
And then want to get the rel of the previous LI which has class="done".

> $('ul.steps li a.selected').prev('li').hasClass('done').html()

I am stuck thinking this way. Maybe anyone can help me in the right direction?
Thanks

Edit: I said Li with class="done". But that has to be an :
What I want:
I want to select the current a (class="selected") (=3)
And then want to get the rel of the previous a which has class="done".

Edit2:

> ```
> <ul class="steps anchor">
> <li><a href="#step-1" class="done" isdone="1" rel="1"><label class="stepNumber">1</label></a></li>
> <li><a href="#step-2" class="done" isdone="1" rel="2"><label class="stepNumber">2</label></a></li>
> <li><a href="#step-3" class="done" isdone="1" rel="3"><label class="stepNumber">3</label></a></li>
> <li><a href="#step-4" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="4"><label class="stepNumber">4</label></a></li>
> <li><a href="#step-5" class="disabled" isdone="0" rel="5"><label class="stepNumber">5</label></a></li>
> <li><a href="#step-6" class="selected" isdone="1" rel="6"><label class="stepNumber">6</label></a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

I have updated my Li structure. Now say I am at LI 6. I want to go to the previous LI with a[class='done']. So a[rel=3]. Your anwsers always give the first LI back (1).

Comment: Will it *always* be previous to the `li.selected`? Because `$('ul.steps').find('.done').attr('rel');` would *seem* more efficient.

Comment: Yes I only what one previous step. Because there are more a's with class="done". So only -1 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the element that way *which is not efficient*, you can use `prevAll` all method:

```
$('a.selected').parent().prevAll('li:has("a.done")').find('a').attr('rel');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pn72t/

Or:

```
$('a.selected').closest('ul').find("a.done:first").attr('rel')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I edited my startpost. I want the previous A close to the selected A. This always gives the first one. I should had made a clearer example. My excuse.

Comment: @SativaNL You are welcome, have you tested it? It works with your update too http://jsfiddle.net/QVV5W/

Comment: Thanks for your time! It's working!! I awarded you with a point!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.steps li a.selected').closest("ul").find("a.done").attr('rel')
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CnkNX/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get` method to retrieve any element from 'a.done`

```
 $($('a.selected').closest('ul').find("li a.done").get(0)).attr('rel')
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gpznn/2/

Comment: Now your code has a syntax error, `get` converts the jQuery object to a DOM Element object which has no `attr` method. You can use `first` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('ul.steps li a.selected').closest('ul').find("li a.done:first").attr('rel')
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/zwLaG/1/